# Converting HDF5 data to suitable types for training a machine learning model in Julia

Tags: dataframe, julia

I have an HDF5 file consisting of 14 feature columns and 1 label column and am looking to train a Random Forest model in Julia using DataFrames.jl and MLJ.jl. I'm running into issues converting the HDF5 data into the proper types for the model to accept.

Here's what I'm doing.

```
using MLJ 
using DataFrames

filepath = "./data/raw_Vortex.h5"
currset = HDF5.h5open(filepath)
x = currset["X"]
y = currset["Y"]
X_DF = DataFrames.DataFrame(x[:,:], :auto)
Y_DF = DataFrames.DataFrame(reshape(y[:],(12878391, 1)), :auto)

X_DF
2878391×14 DataFrame12878366 rows omitted
Row x1  x2  x3  x4  x5  x6  x7  x8  x9  x10 x11 x12 x13 x14
Float64 Float64 Float64 Float64 Float64 Float64 Float64 Float64 Float64 Float64 Float64 Float64 Float64 Float64
RFC = @load RandomForestClassifier pkg=MLJScikitLearnInterface
default_model = RFC(n_estimators=14)

Y_DF
12878391×1 DataFrame12878366 rows omitted
Row x1
Int64


evaluate(default_model, X_DF, Y_DF) 

┌ Warning: The number and/or types of data arguments do not match what the specified model
│ supports. Suppress this type check by specifying `scitype_check_level=0`.
│ 
│ Run `@doc MLJScikitLearnInterface.RandomForestClassifier` to learn more about your model's requirements.
│ 
│ Commonly, but non exclusively, supervised models are constructed using the syntax
│ `machine(model, X, y)` or `machine(model, X, y, w)` while most other models are
│ constructed with `machine(model, X)`.  Here `X` are features, `y` a target, and `w`
│ sample or class weights.
│ 
│ In general, data in `machine(model, data...)` is expected to satisfy
│ 
│     scitype(data) <: MLJ.fit_data_scitype(model)
│ 
│ In the present case:
│ 
│ scitype(data) = Tuple{Table{AbstractVector{Continuous}}, Table{AbstractVector{Count}}}
│ 
│ fit_data_scitype(model) = Tuple{Table{<:Union{AbstractVector{<:Count}, AbstractVector{<:Continuous}}}, AbstractVector{<:Finite}}
└ @ MLJBase ~/.julia/packages/MLJBase/fEiP2/src/machines.jl:230
```

Does anyone have suggestions on how I should convert the data to the proper types? I'm asking here because I'm having a hard time finding information on the Continous, Count, and Finite types in the documentation.